# How can I see distance between two pins in xamarin forms and get the distance as a string?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pins on the map with long and latitude and I wish to see the distance between them. 
This is what I have so far.

```
        var myPin = new Pin ();
        myPin.Label = "pin1";
        myPin.Address = "test1";
        myPin.Position = new Position(37.797513, -122.402068);

        myPin.Label = "pin2";
        myPin.Address = "test2";
        myPin.Position = new Position(37.7, -122.3);

        mymap.Pins.Add(myPin);
```

So two different pins on my map. How can I see the distance between these two in km? My goal is to make a label with the distance (km) as the text.

(I have a customer renderer base ready incase the only way to solve the distancefunction is via a renderer).

Comment: do you just want to draw a line between the points?  Or calculate a route?  Or just drop a label with distance on it?

Comment: a label with distance on it. updated the post about it to be clearer

Comment: the standard Forms map doesn't support that.  You would need to create a custom renderer for that.  You would probably also need to use a native platform method to calculate the distance.

Comment: I have a custom renderer (I use it as a line between two points right now and also an image on the pin) so I have that base ready. Is there any useful links that could guide me how to get the distance between two points?

Comment: in iOS, use CLLocation DistanceFrom(). In Android, Location DistanceBetween()

Comment: thanks alot! will look it up and see if i can solve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if u have two pins you have their longitude and latitude values , so can calculate the distance between em using below code (taken from [geodatasource.com](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/c-sharp))

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  double theta = lon1 - lon2;
  double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = Math.Acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit == 'K') {
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
  } else if (unit == 'N') {
    dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }
  return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
}
```

so basically you just need one starting reference of lat/long value from where you will take reference for further pin to show this distance as a label

Comment: It's been a bit of a difficult mathematical operation. What I can not solve is the unit of length that is returned with return(dist). What can be done "double dist" to convert this to kilometers?

Answer (score 1):

There is one built into the [Location](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Locations.Location.DistanceBetween/p/System.Double/System.Double/System.Double/System.Double/System.Single[]/) class

```
public static Void DistanceBetween (Double startLatitude, Double startLongitude, Double endLatitude, Double endLongitude, Single[] results)
```

See this option also using the CoreLocation class

[Calculate distance between two positions](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3424/calculate-distance-between-two-positions)